# XBee connected to ttyusb0 reconnects to ttyusb 1

Tags: usb, wifi

I hope you can give me a hint of what is going on...
I have a raspi b+ and I have a Asus USB N10 nano connected directly to raspi's USB. I also have a hub usb auto powered DLink DUB H4. And connected to the hub I have a xbee connected XBee USB explorer.
Normally the xbee is connected to /dev/ttyusb0. My problem comes after a random time (normally more than a day) I detect the ttyusb0 is not present and typing dmesg I get a lot of errors -71 and finally I see the sentence the "ftdi is now disconnected from /dev/ttyUSB0" and at the end of dmesg I see the another saying "ftdi now connected to /dev/ttyUSB1".

Then my code getting data from ttyusb0 doesn't get anything and makes code much more difficult. And what is more worrying.. Why does it reconnects itself. Moreover a few when that happens the WiFi module also seems to stop, but I'm not sure of that.

Do you know what might be the problem? Power perhaps? But xbee is connected to powered USB via the hub. Perhaps the USB cable that connects the USB explorer to the raspi is the problem?

I'm thinking of using slice of pi in order to connected xbee directly to the raspi.

Any help?? Please... I'm kind of desperate.

Thank you very much!!